# Recovering VBA modules from corrupt Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook that suddenly got corrupted.  I am trying to recover the VBA code from it.  I can open the workbook in Protected View by opening a blank Excel instance and then using Excel to open the workbook, but when I click "Enable Editing" or try to open the workbook from Windows, it hangs.

I just want to recover the VBA.  But when the workbook is in Protected View, I can't view the VBA project; it just doesn't appear in the VBE Project Explorer.

Any ideas?

Comment: [take a look here, though it's old](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/recover-vba-code-corrupted-xls-file-t955172.html) or [this newer one](http://geekswithblogs.net/msoffice/archive/2013/03/08/effective-methods-to-recover-macros-in-ms-excel.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sigil's solution has worked for me. Instead of steps 3-5, however, I found it safer to export the module(s) and then import them into the desired workbook. This also has the added advantage of having the macro(s) always available.

Follow these steps:

1. Click the Start menu (Windows 7 and 8), and then type "excel /safe" in the Search box (right above Start: box has gray 'Search programs and files' text)
2. Open the corrupted workbook
3. Open the VBA editor (Alt+F11)
4. Right-click on the module you want to recover and click 'Export File...'. Choose a location, type a name, and save your module. Repeat for all modules you will need.
5. Close the corrupted workbook
6. Create a new workbook or open the workbook in which you want to use the macro(s)
7. Open the VBA editor (Alt+F11)
8. Right-click on the VBA Project that has the filename of your workbook, and select Import File...'. Navigate to the exported VBA module and click Open. The module will now be a part of your workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by starting Excel in Safe Mode and copying the VBA objects to a new book.

1. In Win7, go to the Start menu and then in the search box, type
   "excel /safe".
2. Open the corrupt book.
3. Open a new book.
4. Go to the VBA
   Editor.
5. Drag the modules and class modules into the new book's
   project.

Comment: For Win10: hold down Ctrl before starting Excel then click Yes when prompted to open in Safe Mode.